# Ignore prototype.js when debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, prototypejs

I am working with some existing Javascript code that has been built on top of Prototype.js. I need to work out where in this code something is happening. Ideally, I could use the "Break on next" feature in Firebug. Unfortunately, this feature is made redundant because all event handlers are wrapped around Prototype.js. How can I get a "Break on next" feature (I don't care if it's in Firefox or Chrome) that will ignore certain files, so that it will only break on the next line executed within a certain file?

For reference, I spent a long long time using "Step into" after using Break on next with the hope of eventually reaching this code I need to debug. I literally never reached my own code, yet I know it executed because of what changed in the browser. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is the "something" you're looking for?  you might have a much easier time with a mutation observer, breakpoint break-on-ajax, etc.

Comment: I don't know what mutation observers are, and I don't know how to do a break-on-ajax. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping you'd tell me what you're trying to do so I'd know which thing to explain  :)  Here's a quick general answer, for Firebug:

- The Net panel has a "Break on XHR" button on the top left.  Click it, and any XMLHttpRequest (that is, ajax request) will halt execution and drop you into the debugger.
- Similarly, right-click any element on the HTML panel and check one of the "Break on..." boxes to break when an element changes in some way.

When the thing you want to debug happens, you can just look at the call stack and see what code ultimately triggered the breakpoint.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what I'm looking for.

Comment: "I need to work out where in this code **something** is happening."  what is "something"?

Comment: I have no idea. It's what I'm trying to find out. I know that's not very helpful but that's literally all I have to go on. All I know is that I change the selected option in a radio button group, and something changes on the page. I'm trying to use the Break on XHR" function now.

Comment: With respect, I'm not sure my question required knowing what "something" is.